# Cannot change value in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-espresso

I'm writing UI test for my application and I need to set up some values in `SharedPreferences` before every test.

This is how I prepare `SharedPreferences` in parent of every activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set up sharedPreferences by the default file
    if (mSharedPreferences == null) {
        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Globals.PREFS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        //check if preferences are loaded
        if (mSharedPreferences.getString(Globals.ARTICLES_DETAIL_FILENAME, null) == null)
        {
            //not loaded, load default values
            loadDefaultSetting();
        }
    }
```

In test I tried to use similar approach.

```
@Before
public void init() {
    Intents.init();

    context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Globals.PREFS_FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Globals.ALLOW_QUANTITY_CHANGE, false);
    editor.putBoolean(Globals.LOOP_ROWS_DIALOG, false);
    editor.commit();
}
```

But when activity is calling for `Globals.ALLOW_QUANTITY_CHANGE`, it will get `true`, which is default non-changed value.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting question +1.  And I wonder whether Espresso will actually hit the real shared preferences, or could there be some mocking happening under the hood.

Comment: What is the `context` in the test? Which package name does it represent? Maybe it creates 2 different sharedPreferences files, one for each context. Try to get sharedPrefs like this: `getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)` without the name part.

Comment: @HedShafran Thanks for reply. I guess, it was really something with bad context. Now I tried to used `getApplicationContext` in parent and it looks like test can now set up `sharedPreferences` correctly.